# Magento 2 Product Image are not showing on cart page and checkout page

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, magento2.2, magento2.2.2

Product Image are displaying fine on the category page or list page and product description page but it's not showing on cart page and checkout page.

I have tried following command:-

- php bin/magento cache:clean

  php bin/magento cache:flush

  php bin/magento setup:upgrade

  php bin/magento setup:di:compile

  php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f

  php bin/magento catalog:images:resize

  php bin/magento indexer:reindex

Here all the product image are displaying properly on the list page but...its not showing on cart page. Please help me.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you found something for that ?

Answer (score 0):

Check Below admin path setting:

```
Stores -> Configuration -> Sales -> Checkout -> Shopping Cart -> Configurable Product Image
```

Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: That is by default setting of magento, and that is not an issues